# After $10$ minutes, what is the probability that the fly is back on $A$?

Tags: probability

A fly is walking on a hexagon, at random. The fly starts at vertex $A$. After a minute, it moves to one of the two adjacent vertices. After $10$ minutes, what is the probability that the fly in back on $A$?

Comment: This is the 3rd probability question you've posted today - and none have them have shown any working! Can you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: I tried to make a state diagram, but it got too big.

Comment: @heyhuehei There are only 6 states, the vertices of the hexagon, with 12 steps; one from each vertex to the next and one from each vertex to the previous.

Comment: @user159813 It will, but I rather like Mathmo123's solution.  Quite a bit easier than finding the tenth power of a six by six matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Label the vertices as $0,1,2,3,\ldots ,5$ with $A$ being $0$. Consider addition modulo $6$. At each minute, we either add or subtract $1$. For example, one option after $10$ minutes would be $+1, +1, +1, -1, +1, +1, +1, -1, +1, +1$ which sum to $6 \equiv 0 \pmod 6$, so this option gets us back to $A$.

1. How many routes are possible in total?
2. In order to get back to $A$, we must either sum to $0$ - in which case, the number of $+1$'s is equal to the number of $-1$'s, or we must sum to $\pm 6$. Can you count the possible solutions here?

Comment: To count, we recall that the fly must take $10$ steps, of which $n$ go to the right and $10 - n$ go to the left, in order to end up $2n - 10$ spaces to the right of its starting point. Knowing how many ways we can choose which steps go to the right, we end up with the same three terms as in the triangle used by @Asimov. Very nice.

Comment: @Mathmo123: 1.        $2^{10}$                 2. 10, but I also need to count the numbers that can sum to 6/-6, which is also the partitions. Would I just find the partitions of 6 and multiply by 2 (to cover the partitions of -6)? And are partitions such as 2+3, 3+2 considered distinct?

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could use a Markov Chain.

Find $[\mathbf P^{10}]_{1,1}$; the first column and row entry of:

$$\mathbf P^{10} = \dfrac 1{2^{10}}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{10}$$

Comment: It's also possible to get the probability generating function from the matrix, and thus the closed form. The general form for that entry would be: $$\mathbb{P}\left( n\right) =\frac{1}{3}\,\left( \frac{1}{{2}^{n}}+\frac{{\left( -1\right) }^{n}}{{2}^{n}}\right) +\frac{1}{6}\,\left( 1+{\left( -1\right) }^{n}\right) $$

Answer (score 5):

My method: Make a pascal triangle.

Each time it breaks represents the fly going left or going right. The number at any point is how many possibilities that the fly is there after that many minutes (1 row is 1 min)

On the 11th row (after 10 minutes, with minute 0 being row 1), add up the middle term, the term 3 to the left of it, and 3 to the right of it (the reason you do 3 rather than 6 is that only the even numbers are shown in the 11th row, so 3 over is 6 more or less. After 10 steps, the only possible sum is even)

Edit: read the comments for further elaboration, with some possibly helpful pictures

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is this a kind of state diagram? If so, row $i$ will contain $2^{i-1}$ terms...

Comment: It really wont. Going forward, back, forward, and going forward, forward, back, or even back, forward, forward will end up at the same place. The 11th row will have 11 numbers. Each number will represent how many ways there are to end up at that spot

Comment: In case you dont know what a pascal triangle looks like :http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Pascal%27s_triangle_5.svg

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean. This is a more computational version of my method above - ultimately you are summing ${10\choose 5} + {10\choose 2}+{10\choose 8}$... constructing Pascal's triangle by hand seems quite an inefficient way of doing this. I'm not sure I fully understand your explanation of why we only sum the middle term and those three to the left and right of it.

Comment: The middle term is $\binom{10}{5}$ and the ones three to each side are $\binom{10}{2}$ and $\binom{10}{8}$. As you can see, another way to show pascals triangle is with binomials : http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/34/PascalsTriangleCoefficient.jpg

Comment: I like this method personally because it helps illustrate the reason why these are the right ones to calculate, and shows the general form for any other wanted locations/times

Comment: If you take the step "make a Pascal's triangle" as a description of a way the problem _could_ be solved rather than literal instructions how to solve it, you find that the answer is $\binom{10}{2} + \binom{10}{5} + \binom{10}{8}$ (as noted in the previous comments), so the amount of calculation is actually just what you require to compute that sum.

Comment: @DavidK Indeed. This isnt the computationally easiest way. It shows the method, and the reason. It shows a general case, and why it works. Also, it requires simple math, so that basic level math students may still benefit from it.